# Click Event Delayed on Safari Mobile

Tags: html, jquery, ios, iphone, safari

This should be very simple, particularly given that there are a number of similar issues out there that have already been solved, but for some reason I cannot get it to work.

I have divs on a page tied to a class called "thing". When a user clicks on elements with the class "item", I want all of the divs with the class "thing" to be removed immediately. It works perfectly fine on the web, but not on mobile safari. On mobile, the elements remain after the "click" until I subsequently swipe on the page. Once I swipe post-click, elements are removed. It is as if the "click" is not viewed as a "touch".

Per other proposed solutions, I've added `<meta content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">`, "touchstart" event, and `html {touch-action: manipulation;}` css.

**HTML**

```
<div class="thing"></div>
```

**JS**

```
// On click
$(".item").on("click touchstart", function () {
    $(".thing").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user clicks/touchs an element with the class "item", I make an API call via ajax. I ended up exploiting the success function in ajax to remove elements with the class "thing":

```
var success = function (response) {
        $(".thing").remove();
    }
```

The biggest issue here is elements with the class "thing" are not removed until the API call returns successfully. Certainly, I'd prefer to remove the elements as soon as I observe the click event, but I can't get it to work as expected on Safari mobile.

The solution is better than waiting to remove the elements until the user swipes a second time.